# Entity Framework Reload() Error Invalid operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

```
myEntities dc = new myEntities();
...

//i show the table data to user

mainSearchedData = dc.Invoice.ToList();
gvMain.DataSource = mainSearchedData;

//then i change some data in the table(Somewhere else in the code) and save 
//it    
dc.SaveChanges(); //(the change is successfull i can se it in SSMS)

//since if i just use the gvMain.datasource set it wont load the changes 
//that has been made in the tabel i want to reload

dc.Entry(dc).Reload();  <-- This is causing the error
```

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type myEntities is not
>   part of the model for the current context."

I am open for a solution without the `Reload()` method how to cause the entity framework to actually load the modified data

Comment: `Reload()` loads a single entity. You're passing the entire `DbContext`. That's not supported like that. Instead show how you load and update your entities and figure out how to reload a collection.

Comment: Why not read again the invoice table? Either you keep those changes you made in an object, or you have to get again from the DB?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso i did read the invoice table again right under this code but it didn't load the changes. To be honest i solved it by putting the context in a using and reload the tables like that. I dont feel like its the best solution instead of Reloading 1 table but i didn't find any better.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you give me an example for a single entity then because the name "entity" is not telling too much for begginers sadly.